# How to upload multiple docs/pdf files to AWS from iOS application simultaneoulsy

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, amazon-s3

I am fetching multiple files (docs/pdfs) from iCloud/Dropbox to my iOS (Swift) app and trying to uploading them to AWS.
I have seen AWS documentation for uploading the files to AWS one by one (not multiple at a time).

I am trying to uploading multiple files same time to AWS.
I have array which contains multiple document/pdfs paths.

I have seen following code in AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-ios-s3-transfermanager.html).

```
let uploadingFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "your/file/path/myTestFile.txt")

let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()

uploadRequest.bucket = "myBucket"
uploadRequest.key = "myTestFile.txt"
uploadRequest.body = uploadingFileURL

transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in

    if let error = task.error as? NSError {
        if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain, let code = AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code) {
            switch code {
            case .cancelled, .paused:
                break
            default:
                print("Error uploading: \(uploadRequest.key) Error: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Error uploading: \(uploadRequest.key) Error: \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }

    let uploadOutput = task.result
    print("Upload complete for: \(uploadRequest.key)")
    return nil
})
```

how to move forward on this task?

Comment: Call `.upload` multiple times?

Comment: But, how to call the api multiple times with array, how to make it loop here?

Comment: `urls.forEach{ // Create upload request; transferManager.upload(request).continueWith(...) }`?

Comment: will it execute every request upload completion, then start with next url?

Comment: But, here, the list of urls is listed in tableview, so, it like, tableview contains with urls along with Send option, so, once user tapped on Send button, it should send to AWS and need to show indicator for each cell, how to achieve this?

Comment: In this question is nothing about table views, send buton, indicator for each cell. Please open new question(s) for those with where you are stuck, since Stackoverflow is not here to write applications for you.

Comment: I understood, but, In this question I already stated, I want to send multiple urls to AWS simultaneously, So, In that I can set loaders for each send request. Anyway thanks for your quick response

Comment: And calling `.upload(_)` with a different request for each url does not do simultaneous uploading for which you can each give a completion handler?